# Как сохранить цвет кнопки после изменения?

Tags: javascript, css

Есть кнопка, при нажатии на которой она меняет цвет.
Подскажите, как сохранить эти изменения?

#### Html:

```
<span id="like" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
<span id="dislike" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#like").click(function(){
        $("#like").addClass("green");
        $("#dislike").removeClass("red");  
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dislike").click(function(){
        $("#dislike").addClass("red");
        $("#like").removeClass("green");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, использовать [локальное хранилище](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)

```
// пишем
localStorage.setItem("someVal", "val");
// читаем
console.log( "someVal = " + localStorage.getItem("someVal"));
```

Comment: Я новичок с JavaScriptim работаю недавно. Подскажите пожалуйста а как  внедрить это на свой код.

Comment: я не видел ваш код, и я написал как использовать в любом коде.

Comment: <span id="like" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ></span>
  <span  id="dislike" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" ></span>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#like").click(function(){
        $("#like").addClass("green");
        $("#dislike").removeClass("red");

Comment: не могли бы вы оформить его в вопросе?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var stage = localStorage.getItem("stage");
    if(stage){
        $("#like").addClass("green");
        $("#dislike").removeClass("red");  
    }else{
        $("#dislike").addClass("red");
        $("#like").removeClass("green");
    }
    $("#like").click(function(){
        $("#like").addClass("green");
        $("#dislike").removeClass("red");
        localStorage.setItem("stage", true);
    });
    $("#dislike").click(function(){
        $("#dislike").addClass("red");
        $("#like").removeClass("green");
        localStorage.setItem("stage", false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

С использованием *localStorage*, как предложили выше, реализация будет выглядеть примерно так:

HTML:

```
<span class="vote">
  <span data-action="like" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
  <span data-action="dislike" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>
</span>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*
    текущее состояние:

    -1  дислайк
     0  по умолчанию (без голоса)
     1  лайк
   */
  var state = localStorage.getItem('liked');

  // элемент, содержащий кнопки
  var elClass = '.vote';

  // лайк: меняем стили и помещаем liked:1 в хранилище
  var like = function like() {
    localStorage.setItem('liked', 1);

    var $el = $(elClass);
    $el.find('[data-action="like"]').addClass('green');
    $el.find('[data-action="dislike"]').removeClass('red');
  };

  // дислайк: меняем стили и помещаем liked:-1 в хранилище
  var dislike = function dislike() {
    localStorage.setItem('liked', -1);

    var $el = $(elClass);
    $el.find('[data-action="like"]').removeClass('green');
    $el.find('[data-action="dislike"]').addClass('red');
  };

  // устанавливаем лайк или дислайк при загрузке страницы
  if (state == 1) {
    like();
  } else if (state == -1) {
    dislike();
  }

  // событие на нажатие лайка или дислайка
  $(elClass + ' span').click(function () {
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    action === 'like' ? like() : dislike();
  });
});
```

Используя данный подход можно с легкостью организовать "лайк/дислайк" сразу для несколько сущностей.